# gem のアップデートポリシーとして推奨はありますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

rails で web アプリケーションを開発していると、プロジェクト開始時に比べて、もろもろの最新バージョンが上がっていきます。

- ruby 自体のバージョン
- rails のバージョン
- それ以外の gem のバージョン

rails プロジェクトのアップグレードポリシーとしては、どのようなものが一般的ですか？ (ベストプラクティスのようなものはありますか？)